# Carregar imagem dinamicamente em um grid?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xaml

Tenho esse xaml:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="10" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" >
    <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="{local:ImageResource Operacional.Images.images1.png}" >
       <Image.GestureRecognizers>
           <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTrocaImageTapGestureReconizerTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"></TapGestureRecognizer>
       </Image.GestureRecognizers>
   </Image>
</StackLayout>
```

ao clicar na imagem(Tapa) eu mudo a imagem. Fiz isso no behind e acontece que quando eu clico, a primeira imagem some, mas a segunda não aparece.

```
void OnTrocaImageTapGestureReconizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyImage.Source = "Operacional.Images.fechar1.png";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi assim:

`void OnTrocaImageTapGestureReconizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Operacional.Images.fechar1.png");
 }`